# How can GPT4 be used to create structured meta-data for unstructured data?

Tags: excel, data-engineering, metadata, structured-data, chatgpt

I often ingest unstructured datasets in Excel format, create meta-data, and transform the data in R to create a structured dataset. This includes normalization, so that there is little redundancy in the output tables. The output is *tidy*, whereas the input is in a wide format.

How can I use ChatGPT4 to create a meta-data structure? Can you please suggest a plug-in, and outline the process? Feel free to comment with relevant blog posts.